# What is the Differences Between PyMsSQL and _MSSql Modules

Tags: python, pymssql

I don't understand what is the difference between pymssql and _mssql modules. Which one should i use to connect sql server database ?

Answer (score 5):

According to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/pymssql/9g6JlrB-A_Y

> _mssql module is a low-level solution, which directly communicates with SQL Server. pymssql is higher level wrapper that provides DB-API compliance. If you don't need DB-API compliance, just use _mssql, it is easier to
>   use